# How is designing a compiler with an other language's compiler better than designing the compiler with assembly language?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Suppose we have a language X whose compiler is designed in language Y, where language Y's compiler is designed in assembly language. Now, to execute a piece of code written in X, the instructions are compiled with the help of language Y i.e., the instructions in X are presented as input to Y (which serves as a compiler to X) where Y's compiler executes them and produces the compiled code for X.But here the instructions presented to Y must also be compiled by the assembly language.

Here instructions in Y must be compiled in order to compile the instructions in X. Why is this even necessary?

When we compile instructions in X directly using assembly code isn't it easier than the above case?

Comment: You're obviously free to do it either way..

Comment: By `designing with language ...` do you mean `writing in language ...`? Have you ever tried to write a non-trivial Program in assembler? The answer is the same as with any other type of program: because it is easier, faster and less error prone.

Comment: The backend of the compiler is the most critical and expensive part of creating a compiler.  The code generator is do-able but a good optimizer is a very significant investment and critical to perf.  And then you get to do it over and over again for every architecture you need to support.  Leveraging somebody else's hard work is by far the smartest thing to do.  LLVM is the thousand pound gorilla,  the JVM and .NET also make it easy.  And the JavaScript jitters now universally available get more and more use today.

Comment: You seem to think of programming languages as *programs*. This is not the case, a programming language doesn't take any input.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing of any significance is ***easier*** in assembly. Assembly is just another syntax that, itself, has to be ultimately compiled so as to produce machine code.

Back to language 'X': Depends on the outcome you want. Is the language going to bootstrap itself? If so, that is done incrementally and the intermediate or initial compilation can be done in any suitable language. Eventually you phase out the intermediate language as yours takes over the work. If you ***never*** plan on bootstrapping and/or self-hosting than the most obvious choice would be the most flexible and portable language requiring minimal effort to manage change, this is typically a higher level language than 'assembly'.